# How to correctly list items in different categories? General programming technique

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a datatable which contains items and their categories. I want to list them as the following.

```
<h3>CATEGORY 1</h3>
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>

<h3>CATEGORY 2</h3>
<ul>
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>item 20</li>
    <li>item 30</li>
</ul>
```

My actual data looks like below:

```
$table =  array(
             array(
                "cat" => "Vegetables",
                "item" => "mydonose"
             ),
             array(
                 "cat" => "Vegetables",
                 "item" => "carrot"
             ),
              array(
                "cat" => "Vegetables",
                "item" => "tomato"
                ),
             array(
                 "cat" => "Fruits",
                 "item" => "apple"
             ),
              array(
                "cat" => "Fruits",
                "item" => "banana"
                ),
             array(
                 "cat" => "Fruits",
                 "item" => "orange"
             ),
              array(
                "cat" => "Other",
                "item" => "mushroom"
                ),
             array(
                 "cat" => "Other",
                 "item" => "olive"
             )     
    );
```

I am trying to list data using the code below.

```
$cat = "";

foreach($table as $t):

    if($cat !== $t["cat"]):

        echo "<h3>".$t["cat"]."</h3>";
        echo "<ul>";
    endif;

    echo "<li>".$t["item"]."</li>";

    if($cat !== $t["cat"]):
        echo "</ul>"; //this part is problem
        $cat = $t["cat"];
    endif;            

endforeach;
```

But I cannot figure out on which condition I should echo `</ul>` closing tag. My final output should be like:

```
<h3>Vegetables</h3>
<ul>
    <li>mydonose</li>
    <li>carrot</li>
    <li>tomato</li>
</ul>
<h3>Fruits</h3>
<ul>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>orange</li>
</ul>
<h3>Other</h3>
<ul>
    <li>mushroom</li>
    <li>olive</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: just a side note, i don't think `!==` is correct?! it should be `!=` may be some PHP expert confirms or denies this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code:

```
$cat = "";

foreach($table as $t):

    if($cat != $t["cat"]):
        if(strlen($cat) >  1) {
            echo "</ul>";
        }
        $cat = $t["cat"];
        echo "<h3>".$t["cat"]."</h3>";
        echo "<ul>";
    endif;

    echo "<li>".$t["item"]."</li>";


endforeach;
```

Comment: it is not closing ul elements

Comment: @zkanoca in case of the accepted answer (as your approach) make sure your array is sorted based on category otherwise it can lead you to multiple ul for same category.

Comment: @Suchit exactly, I suppose he retrieves the data already ordered :)

Comment: @Suchit of course it is ordered. I retrieve data from DB using orderby cat clause

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
$arr=array();
foreach($table as $key=>$val){
    $arr[$val['cat']][]=$val['item'];
}


foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    echo "<h3>$key</h3>";
    if(sizeof($val) > 0){
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($val as $key1=>$val1){
        echo "<li>$val1</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome. What if I use objects?

Comment: you can convert them to array.

Answer (score 0):

i have noticed the selected answer,
this sol works too and you don't have to create another array

more details are included in code comments.

```
foreach($table as $t):

//if first loop: print category, open a list, assign cat value
    if($cat==""){
        echo "<h3>".$t["cat"]."</h3>\n";
        echo "<ul>\n";
        $cat = $t["cat"];
    }

    //if still in same cat, add item to list
    if ($cat == $t["cat"]){
        echo "<li>".$t["item"]."</li>\n";
    }else{
    //if new cat, close list, print new cat, open new list, add current item to list, assign cat value
        echo "</ul>\n"; 
        echo "<h3>".$t["cat"]."</h3>\n";
        echo "<ul>\n";
        echo "<li>".$t["item"]."</li>\n";
        $cat = $t["cat"];
    }
endforeach;
```

Comment: It is not about whether  answer is accepted or not , we need to help with the   most suitable answert

Comment: @Suchit exactly, that is my point, and that's why i posted the answer although there is an accepted answer :) this may help someone else some day ... i hope :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$table =  array(
 array(
  "cat" => "Vegetables",
  "item" => "mydonose"
  ),
 array(
   "cat" => "Vegetables",
   "item" => "carrot"
   ),
   ...
 );

// Key data by the category.
function group_table($carry, $value) {
  $carry[$value['cat']][] = array('item' => $value['item']);
  return $carry;
}

// Output the category and its child items.
function output_category($items, $category) {
  return '<h3>' . $category . '</h3>'
    . (count($items) ? '<ul>'
    .  implode('', array_map('output_items', $items))
    . '</ul>' : '');
}

// Output individual category items.
function output_items($item) {
  return '<li>' . $item . '</li>';
}

// Regroup data by key.
$grouped_table_data = array_reduce($table, 'group_table', []);

// Apply UI function to data.
$output = array_map('output_category', $grouped_table_data, array_keys($grouped_table_data));

// Print to screen.
print implode('', $output);
```